# Crashreport indicates KVO connection between object and parameter which was never initiated in code

Tags: ios, memory, crash, key-value-observing

Recently I have gotten some very strange crashes on HockeyApp:

> Application Specific Information:  Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance
>   0x13ef90530 of class FPPhoto was deallocated while key value observers
>   were still registered with it. Current observation info:
>   NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x13e9e8bb0 ( NSKeyValueObservance
>   0x13ef36810: Observer: 0x13e5a95f0, Key path: fractionCompleted,
>   Options: New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property:
>   0x13ef795d0 )'

I understand the basis of the crashreport and this can very well be true as I have KVO observers all over the place in my app, also connected to objects of type **FPPhoto**

The strange thing I wonder about is the name of the parameter: **(Key path: fractionCompleted)** We actaully have a parameter called  **fractionCompleted**, but that is in a totally different place in the application. We add KVO to **fractionCompleted** to track upload progress. **fractionCompleted** KVO listener is though never added to any object of kind **FPPhoto** in the code.

I guess either it's the crash report that got the parameter/class names mixed up or can it be worse, -> some kind of memory mixup at runtime to make KVO attach to the wrong object?

Any ideas how this can happen?

Comment: I would reevaluate your code; it's much more likely an error in your code than in the bug reporting or KVO system.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding two symbolic breakpoints on:

```
-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]
```

and

```
-[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:]
```

**With the condition:**

> (BOOL)[@"fractionCompleted" isEqualToString:(id)$r8]

and

> (BOOL)[@"fractionCompleted" isEqualToString:(id)$rdx]

**Then set an action as a Debugger Command:**

> po $rdx

and

> po $rcx

If you're curious about why the registers change, that is because OS X follows the System V ABI for register calling conventions.
Arguments for a method go into:

> rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9

In that argument order.  Because Objective-C messages get compiled into `objc_msgsend(receiver, selectorname, argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4)`

We have to change the registers being compared because those 2 `-addObserver` signatures differ in the location of their arguments for the notification name and the `observer` object.

Using these breakpoint will help you identify which objects get registered as an observer, so you can make sure they are deallocated & remove observation properly.

EDIT: Just realized that you are not using `NSNotificationCenter`, just KVO.  But I don't want to delete my answer, so I'm just going to leave it.  It's still applicable, you just need to change the symbol you break on to `- addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`, and you will need to add more conditions because otherwise you will hit that breakpoint 10 times a second.